# What is the best Dictionary with Pronanciation and "click/copy to define/meaning" feature?

Tags: dictionary

I've been looking for a dictionary for my Ubuntu 20 which has a pronunciation feature added to it. Also, it would be great if it works offline and has the feature of click/copy a word to create e pop up with its meaning.

Comment: You might find more answers on SE [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?newreg=644f2ca223894d43a51600e7df318c7d)

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).